# Adding NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

```
NSMutableArray *arrData =[NSMutableArray array];
arrData =[data objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"%@",arrData);
```

NSLog will print  like

```
data = 
(
   {
        date = "2016-01-20";
        "end_time" = "12:25:00";
        "start_time" = "11:00:00";
        "total_units" = 59;
    }
);
```

This data comes from server. Now, I want to add one more dictionary of data to this array coming from the server.

I did the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[newDict setObject:@"2016-01-22" forKey:@"date"];
[arrData addObject:newDict];
```

Now the app crashed. What went wrong?

```
[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4d3914d40
```

Comment: modified this line arrData =[[data objectForKey:@"data"]mutableCopy];

Comment: Make sure your array must be mutable. Try allocating your array like this 

                       `NSMutableArray *arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: OK so you aren't being quite straight here.  You say `NSMutableArray *arrData =[NSMutableArray array];` but I expect you reassign `arrData` from a JSON parse, yes?

Comment: @thanks kb920 ,its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrData =[NSMutableArray array];
```

Is a method from `NSArray` class, which create an `NSArray` instance, not `NSMutableArray` instance.

What you need is, for example:

```
NSMutableArray *arrData =[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW4

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-SW1

Comment: That's isn't true at all.

Comment: I don't believe the OP has presented the question properly.  I believe the `arrData` is later re-assigned with a non-mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[data objectForKey:@"data"]];
```

Use the above code instead.
Your old code just move the pointer of `arrData` to [data objectForKey:@"data"]]. It access the same address

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in [data objectForKey:@"data"])
{
    [arrData addObject:dict];
}
```

now you can add object whwnever you want to add in array

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
arrData = [data[@"data"] mutableCopy];
```

in order to create a mutable copy of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your array must be mutable. Try allocating your array like this

```
 NSMutableArray *arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Assign your response object to your arrData like this

```
NSMutableArray *arrData = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Then do your following stuff and also avoid using new keyword in the start of the variable name.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                       [dict setObject:@"2016-01-22" forKey:@"date"];
                       [arrData addObject:dict];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an NSDictionary object reference to an NSMutableArray object.

```
arrData =[data objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Then, when you try to execute **addObject** method on arrData it crashes because addObject method does not exist for an NSDictionary object.

use :

```
[arrData addObject:[data objectForKey:@"data"]]
```